# large number of large files creating leak while creating zip file

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, zip

```
NSData * buffer = [fileHandle readDataOfLength:chunkSize];
                while ([buffer length] > 0)
                {
                    [streamBIG writeData:buffer];
                    offset += [buffer length];

                    [fileHandle seekToFileOffset:offset];
                    buffer = [fileHandle readDataOfLength:chunkSize];
                }
```

I use these particular process to zip more then 1 file of 25 - 30 MB but these increases memory i.e. live bytes continuously increase till all files are not written, because of which my app crashes

Comment: Could you give a little more context: what are `fileHandle` and `streamBig`, and are you using ARC or not?    It looks like you could probably use an `@autoreleasepool` inside of your while look, though.

Comment: I am not using arc so I used autoreleasepool and it worked, thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this with Auto release pool

```
               NSData * buffer = [fileHandle readDataOfLength:chunkSize];
                while ([buffer length] > 0)
                {
                    @autoreleasepool
                    {
                    [streamBIG writeData:buffer];
                    offset += [buffer length];

                    [fileHandle seekToFileOffset:offset];
                    buffer = [fileHandle readDataOfLength:chunkSize];
                    }
                }
```

it will work...

Comment: thank you so much, it worked, I was placing the autorelease pool in wrong place, really thanks